# TASM generates Illegal instruction, undefined symbol, and unreachable segment errors

Tags: assembly, tasm, x86-16

Assembling my code with TASM 5 and 3 (I tried with both version of TASM) gives me a few errors, and I don't know why!

> ```
> **Error** fonts.txt(4) Illegal instruction
> **Error** fonts.txt(15) Illegal instruction
> **Error** fonts.txt( 148) Undefined symbol: FONT1
> **Error** fonts.txt( 154) Undefined symbol: FONT2
> ```

My code:

```
.MODEL LARGE, PASCAL
.386
.DATA
FONT1
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,048h,048h,030h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,060h,070h,070h,038h,018h,018h,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,044h,0FCh,0F8h,060h,030h,030h,010h,010h,010h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,04Ah,0FEh,0F4h,060h,030h,030h,010h,010h,010h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,04Eh,0F0h,0FEh,07Ch,030h,030h,010h,010h,010h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,038h,02Ch,044h,042h,082h,092h,0FEh,06Ch,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,040h,07Ch,03Ch,004h,004h,004h,006h,007h,003h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,082h,0C6h,0C6h,06Ch,028h,038h,010h,010h,010h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,010h,010h,010h,038h,028h,06Ch,0C6h,0C6h,082h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,070h,0F8h,088h,0F8h,078h,008h,00Ch,00Eh,006h,000h,000h,000h
FONT2
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,048h,048h,030h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,038h,038h,01Ch,00Ch,00Ch,004h,004h,004h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,022h,07Eh,07Ch,030h,018h,018h,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,025h,07Fh,07Ah,030h,018h,018h,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,027h,078h,07Fh,03Eh,018h,018h,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,018h,01Ch,016h,022h,021h,041h,041h,07Fh,036h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,042h,07Eh,03Eh,004h,004h,004h,006h,003h,003h,001h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,041h,063h,063h,036h,014h,01Ch,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,008h,008h,01Ch,014h,036h,063h,063h,041h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,038h,07Ch,044h,07Ch,03Ch,004h,004h,006h,007h,003h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,018h,020h,038h,038h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,01Ch,03Eh,022h,020h,010h,008h,008h,000h,008h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,002h,032h,04Ch,000h,010h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,010h,008h,011h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,00Ch,010h,00Ch,00Ah,014h,008h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,010h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,008h,008h,008h,008h,008h,008h,00Fh,007h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,041h,081h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,020h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,041h,081h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,028h,010h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,050h,020h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,028h,000h,041h,081h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,028h,000h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,010h,028h,000h,041h,081h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,010h,028h,000h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,01Fh,03Fh,060h,044h,040h,061h,03Eh
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,008h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,01Fh,03Fh,060h,04Ah,044h,061h,03Eh
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,038h,010h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,01Fh,03Fh,060h,040h,040h,061h,03Eh
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,01Fh,03Fh,060h,040h,040h,061h,03Eh
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,000h,01Ch,026h,003h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,00Ch,006h,003h,03Fh,03Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,000h,00Ch,006h,003h,03Fh,03Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,002h,007h,003h,003h,006h,00Eh,03Ch,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,002h,000h,002h,007h,003h,003h,007h,00Eh,03Ch,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,004h,00Ah,000h,002h,007h,003h,003h,006h,00Eh,03Ch,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,001h,015h,09Fh,09Eh,098h,088h,088h,0F8h,070h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,001h,049h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,014h,000h,001h,015h,09Fh,09Eh,098h,088h,088h,0F8h,070h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,014h,000h,001h,049h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,003h,005h,015h,09Fh,09Eh,098h,088h,088h,0F8h,070h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,006h,009h,051h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,000h,003h,005h,015h,09Fh,09Eh,098h,088h,088h,0F8h,070h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,004h,000h,006h,009h,051h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,020h,020h,020h,02Eh,031h,021h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 011h,044h,011h,044h,011h,044h,011h,044h,011h,044h,011h,044h,011h,044h,011h,044h
db 055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh,055h,0AAh
db 0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h,0DDh,077h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0F8h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0F8h,018h,0F8h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0F6h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FEh,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0F8h,018h,0F8h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0F6h,006h,0F6h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FEh,006h,0F6h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0F6h,006h,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0F8h,018h,0F8h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0F8h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,01Fh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,01Fh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0FFh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,01Fh,018h,01Fh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,037h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,037h,030h,03Fh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,03Fh,030h,037h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0F7h,000h,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,000h,0F7h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,037h,030h,037h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,000h,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0F7h,000h,0F7h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0FFh,000h,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,000h,0FFh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,03Fh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,01Fh,018h,01Fh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Fh,018h,01Fh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,03Fh,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,0FFh,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h,036h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0FFh,018h,0FFh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,0F8h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Fh,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h,018h
db 0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh
db 0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h,0F0h
db 00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh,00Fh
db 0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,0FFh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,020h,024h,020h,02Eh,031h,021h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,00Ch,01Eh,020h,03Eh,03Eh,040h,080h,080h,0C1h,0FEh,07Ch
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,038h,044h,038h,03Fh,04Fh,080h,080h,0C2h,0FCh,078h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,01Ch,022h,01Ch,0FFh,0E7h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,00Ch,01Eh,020h,0FEh,0FCh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,004h,000h,00Ch,01Eh,020h,03Eh,03Eh,040h,080h,080h,0C1h,0FEh,07Ch
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,010h,000h,038h,044h,038h,03Fh,04Fh,080h,080h,0C2h,0FCh,078h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,008h,000h,01Ch,022h,01Ch,0FFh,0E7h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,004h,000h,00Ch,01Eh,020h,0FEh,0FCh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,002h,000h,002h,047h,085h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,002h,000h,002h,007h,005h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,014h,000h,002h,007h,005h,087h,081h,081h,083h,07Eh,03Ch,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,00Ah,000h,002h,007h,005h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,001h,003h,006h,00Ch,008h,00Ch,086h,083h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,001h,003h,006h,00Ch,008h,00Ch,006h,003h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,005h,00Bh,016h,00Ch,008h,00Ch,086h,083h,0FFh,07Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,005h,00Bh,016h,00Ch,008h,00Ch,006h,003h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,001h,001h,001h,001h,001h,001h,001h,081h,081h,0FEh,07Ch,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,001h,061h,031h,019h,009h,005h,007h,00Eh,038h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,001h,001h,001h,001h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,006h,00Bh,07Fh,0FEh,080h,080h,080h,080h,080h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,006h,00Fh,0FDh,0FFh,006h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,010h,001h,081h,081h,081h,0FEh,07Ch,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,004h,000h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,006h,009h,00Fh,00Fh,003h,00Eh,03Ch,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,004h,00Eh,00Fh,013h,013h,01Fh,00Eh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,010h,0F3h,0F3h,00Ch,004h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,00Ch,01Eh,03Fh,0C9h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,007h,007h,00Eh,083h,081h,0FFh,07Eh,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,006h,00Fh,010h,01Eh,08Fh,081h,081h,0FEh,07Ch,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,001h,001h,0FFh,0FEh,000h,024h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
.CODE
Assume    es:@DATA
public    Font
FONT     proc   PASCAL
lea     bp, FONT1
mov     dx,48
mov     bx,1000h
mov     cx,10
mov     ax,1110h
int     10h
lea     bp,FONT2
mov     dx,128
push    ds
pop     es
mov     bx,1000h
mov     cx,127
mov     ax,1110h
int     10h
ret
FONT   ENDP
END
```

Some friends said: Line 14,15 needed a ":" at end of labels eg.`FONT1:` but these are not a label, these are NAME for a group of "db". When I try to assemble with a colon on the end of the labels (`FONT1:`and `FONT2:`) it gives me these errors:

> ```
> **Error** fonts.txt(4) CS UNREACHABLE FROM CURRENT SEGMENT
> **Error** fonts.txt(15) CS UNREACHABLE FROM CURRENT SEGMENT
> ```

How can I fix this code to avoid these errors?

Comment: Shouting "urgent" multiple times won't get you an answer faster. If anything, only a bunch of downvotes. PS: `font1` **is** a label, and yes it should probably have a colon unless it's on the same line as the `db`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! but as I mented in the the topic "(CS UNREACHABLE FROM CURRENT SEGMENT(for: LINE 4,15))"--->`Font1:` ,`Font2:`

Comment: Then try putting the label on the same line as the `db`, e.g. `Font1 db 000h, ...`

Comment: @Jester I tested! Does not change it! again : (CS UNREACHABLE FROM CURRENT SEGMENT with ":" or without it again :

*-Error-» fonts.txt(4) Illegal instruction

*-Error-» fonts.txt(15) Illegal instruction

*-Error-» fonts.txt( 148) Undefined symbol: FONT1

*-Error-» fonts.txt( 154) Undefined symbol: FONT2

Comment: Assembled fine with TASM 2.0 (the only one I have here).

Comment: _"these are NAME for a group of "db""_ That's exactly what a label is; a convenient name for some location in your program.

Answer (score 1):

I would have put this in a comment but not sure if it would have been legible. With TASM place the label on the line with the data and not by itself. It may work if you simply do something like modifying:

```
FONT1
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,048h,048h,030h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,060h,070h,070h,038h,018h,018h,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
[snip for brevity]
```

to be:

```
FONT1 db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,048h,048h,030h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,060h,070h,070h,038h,018h,018h,008h,008h,008h,000h,000h,000h
[snip for brevity]
```

Do the same for `FONT2`:

```
FONT2 db 000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,048h,048h,030h,000h,000h,000h,000h,000h
db 000h,000h,000h,000h,030h,038h,038h,01Ch,00Ch,00Ch,004h,004h,004h,000h,000h,000h
[snip for brevity]
```

Comment: @Jester : I have a suspicion that he missed it. He might not have understood the follow up comment with the ellipsis.

Comment: That may be true.

Comment: @Jester , Michael Petch  Thanks, I tried it with another compiler  and it work! thaks again!

Comment: @Aryan : The above assembled here with TASM 3

Comment: @Michael Petch yes but first time assembled  it with 3 and 5 and next times with only 5 . At least with Tasm 3 in Dosbox use `Font1 db ,.....` , `Font2 db` it work fine. Now I dont understand differnts between these assembelers!

Answer (score 0):

> "CS unreachable"

I don't have TASM to test, but you are probably building this into exe file, so the `.DATA` is in separate segment after loading the binary, and to get it's full address you have to use also segment register.

The `cs` is pointing to the`.CODE` already, I don't see any further segment register set up (well, you copy `ds` into `es` in the middle of procedure, but that doesn't make any sense to me, as `ds` is undefined).

So what you probably want is to use `mov ax,@DATA` `mov es,ax` somewhere early in your procedure (you may also `push es`/`pop es` at the start/end of procedure to preserve the original content). And do `lea bp,[es:FONT1]` (maybe `lea bp,es:[FONT1]` in TASM), as you already have the `ASSUME` clause there. Also maybe `MOV bp,OFFSET FONT1` would work (I'm not sure what will TASM do with the prefixed lea, I'm a bit worried it will assemble it into machine code with real `es:` prefix, which is pointless, as the `lea` will just set up the `bp`, not accessing memory for real).

About the colon: the MASM/TASM (and actually almost all assemblers out there) syntax is not very coherent, and there're many exceptions, shortcuts and obscure simplifications.

So the:

```
someLabel DB 1
```

Is equal to (more accurate and consistent and recommended by me):

```
someLabel: DB 1
```

In NASM for example you may create labels without colon even on ordinary non-DB lines inside code, but there's still strong recommendation to put colon after every label, to avoid situations where you have for example bad taste for label naming, and you write `loop` as label for your loop, which can be without the trailing colon confused with the `loop` instruction. So adding the colon every time will help the assembler to not mistake any label with something else.

And `FONT1` is not a *NAME* for *GROUP*. It's a label (address) pointing on the next defined machine code byte. And the next machine code byte is defined by the first value in the long `db`. The remaining defined bytes are not related in any way to the `FONT1`, it does compile to the same label whether you would do just `FONT1 DB 1`, or `FONT1 DB 1, 2, 3, 4` ... The first `1` defines byte, and that's the memory address, to where the label `FONT1` is pointing. Remaining bytes are just compiled into machine code following that `1`.

EDIT: also if you don't plan to use MASM, and you have full control over the TASM usage (version + CLI options), I suggest to you to use the TASM "ideal" mode, which has slightly different syntax from MASM (a bit more strict and coherent). And the last time I was using TASM (around 1998), the least bugged version was 3.something, the 4.x did produce wrong machine code even on medium sized source, and 5.x did look almost stable, but on one of my largest sources it did produce wrong machine code too, so I reverted to some late 3.x (can't recall the exact version). But I can't recall to have too much problems with syntax between versions, looks like I wrote the source in compatible way by luck. Anyway, checking the proper TASM documentation for the version you use should help you clarify particular syntax subtleties.

Comment: `someLabel: DB 1` causes the unreachable segment issue as mentioned by the OP and was confirmed under TASM 3. TASM was quirk in this regard. With TASM `someLabel: DB 1` and `someLabel: DB 1` are not always recognized as the same thing which is what part of his problem is.

Comment: @MichaelPetch hm... sad story then. I thought the cause was the `lea` using `FONT1` without segment specification, but then the `bp` implies `ss`, so it does not make any more sense... Not sure if I should delete this answer completely, maybe the OP should let me know, if there's anything in it to get him further.

Comment: Oops I had a type in my comment. Meant `someLabel DB 1` and `someLabel: DB 1`, but yeah in this case the declaration of the fonts themselves poses the issues. Errors generated aren't from within the code.

Comment: Reviewing my only TASM Manual `:` (colon) is considered a code label directive and is assumed to be NEAR. `someLabel:` is the same as `someLabel LABEL NEAR`. In MASM mode it is probably confusing the assembler because it is a near code label in a data segment